# Importing Foreign Drive with Megaraid Webbios

Tags: megaraid, import, drive

I've recently acquired an old server and decided to set it up as a home server. Having never set up a server before, I accidentally cleared a foreign configuration that kept two of my drives on it. Now those two drives are marked as foreign and I haven't been able to figure out how to add them to a new virtual drive. The configuration wizard will not detect them as viable sources for a new virtual drive and scanning for new drives doesn't seem to help.

Is there a way to get the foreign config back that I deleted or to remake a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out yesterday and forgot to update here. In preboot CLI I cleared the foreign config. Not sure if this is the same as what would've happened had I cleared the foreign config via webbios but it worked. Was considering clearing it in webbios but I didn't want to dig myself into a deeper hole with four foreign drives instead of two. Command incase anybody five years down the road is still using a ten year old server: MegaCli -CfgForeign -Clear -aALL

Answer (score 0):

You would have been safe to do it in the WebBios GUI as well.  Does the same thing.  I'm running up against the same issue on an antiquated IBM x3550 M4.